# Javascript - Adding new element to array using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to convert url. Using for loop to extract Acura, Audi. Here what I got so far:

```
var newSrpParams = 'year=2020-2022&make=Acura&make=Audi&model=A3&model=A5&trim=2.0T%20Premium&trim=2.0T%20S%20line%20Premium&normalBodyStyle=Hatchback&normalBodyStyle=Sedan&odometer=13000-38000&internetPrice=20000-50000';

const newSrpParamsArray = newSrpParams.split("&");

var oldSrpParams;

var makes = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < newSrpParamsArray.length; i++){
  if(newSrpParamsArray[i].includes('make')) {
    const make = newSrpParamsArray[i].replace('make=','')
    makes.push(make);
    console.log(makes)
  }
};
```

The result is

```
[ 'Acura' ]
[ 'Acura', 'Audi' ]
```

As you see it has one more array. Is there a way to get only  `[ 'Acura', 'Audi' ]`?

Comment: There is only one array, you just logged the same array twice at different time.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. Just console output outside the for loop

Comment: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI there's a native solution for getting values a from query string, check [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
var newSrpParams = 'year=2020-2022&make=Acura&make=Audi&model=A3&model=A5&trim=2.0T%20Premium&trim=2.0T%20S%20line%20Premium&normalBodyStyle=Hatchback&normalBodyStyle=Sedan&odometer=13000-38000&internetPrice=20000-50000';

const makes = new URLSearchParams(newSrpParams).getAll('make');

console.log(makes);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you are logging the array inside the for loop. If you move it outside you will get

```
['Acura', 'Audi']
```

The Code:

```
var newSrpParams = 'year=2020-2022&make=Acura&make=Audi&model=A3&model=A5&trim=2.0T%20Premium&trim=2.0T%20S%20line%20Premium&normalBodyStyle=Hatchback&normalBodyStyle=Sedan&odometer=13000-38000&internetPrice=20000-50000';

const newSrpParamsArray = newSrpParams.split("&");
console.log(newSrpParamsArray)

var oldSrpParams;

var makes = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < newSrpParamsArray.length; i++){
  if(newSrpParamsArray[i].includes('make')) {
    const make = newSrpParamsArray[i].replace('make=','')
    console.log(make)
    makes.push(make);
  }
};

console.log(makes) // The change
```

Answer (score 0):

You were consoling the results inside the if statement it will run two times. So as a result `make[]` array print two times. That's why you get the two arrays.

```js
var newSrpParams = 'year=2020-2022&make=Acura&make=Audi&model=A3&model=A5&trim=2.0T%20Premium&trim=2.0T%20S%20line%20Premium&normalBodyStyle=Hatchback&normalBodyStyle=Sedan&odometer=13000-38000&internetPrice=20000-50000';

const newSrpParamsArray = newSrpParams.split("&");

var oldSrpParams;

var makes = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < newSrpParamsArray.length; i++){
  if(newSrpParamsArray[i].includes('make')) {
    const make = newSrpParamsArray[i].replace('make=','')
    makes.push(make);
  }
};

console.log(makes)
```

Make sure to console `make[]` from outside of the for a loop. That's only. I couldn't see any other wrong line in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use URLSearchParams?
and you can replace the URL with window.location.href

```
let url = new URL(`http://localhost?year=2020-2022&make=Acura&make=Audi&model=A3&model=A5&trim=2.0T%20Premium&trim=2.0T%20S%20line%20Premium&normalBodyStyle=Hatchback&normalBodyStyle=Sedan&odometer=13000-38000&internetPrice=20000-50000`)
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search).getAll("make")
console.log(params)
```